# MySQL Stored Procedure : add condition for spatial data type

Tags: mysql, csv, triggers, spatial

A simple BEFORE INSERT Stored Procedure fails with 1st row of the dataset including the columns names instead of data :

```
SET NEW.`COORD` = POINT (NEW.`GPS_Longitude`, NEW.`GPS_Latitude`)
```

I'm trying to insert a condition to skip the first row :

```
IF ((`GPS_Longitude` BETWEEN 0 AND 90) AND (`GPS_Latitude` BETWEEN 0 AND 90)) THEN
SET NEW.`COORD` = POINT (NEW.`GPS_Longitude`, NEW.`GPS_Latitude`)
```

But I can't save it and the error message is not clear.

As per request, some more details below, but I'm using PhpMyAdmin interface, so the code above is what that really counts. Same for the data, it's provided by another software (with the fields names in the first row - that I'd like to skip).

```
CREATE TABLE `obs` (
`COORD` point DEFAULT NULL,
`GPS_Longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
`GPS_Latitude` decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
)

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `geom` BEFORE INSERT ON `obs` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`COORD` = POINT (NEW.`GPS_Longitude`, NEW.`GPS_Latitude`)
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What does not work :

importing a .csv **through the phpmyadmin interface** (even when checking "ignore errors on insert"), with values

```
'GPS_Longitude', 'GPS_Latitude'
46.1693780, 6.0487320
...
```

The (latest) trigger that does not work :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `geom` 
BEFORE INSERT
ON `obs` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`COORD` = CASE WHEN NEW.`GPS_Longitude` BETWEEN 0 AND 90 AND NEW.`GPS_Latitude` BETWEEN 0 AND 90
                       THEN POINT (NEW.`GPS_Longitude`, NEW.`GPS_Latitude`)
                       ELSE POINT (0, 0)
                       END;
```

Comment: Provide the code which allows to reproduce - CREATE TABLE, complete SP/trigger code (even incorrect), INSERT query and desired final data state. *A simple BEFORE INSERT Stored Procedure* Either stored procedure or BEFORE INSERT trigger. Not both.

Comment: I added the details. COORD value for the 1st row with the columns titles doesn't matter (in fact I can't set a default value for this type), skipping that row would be fine (but the condition I added didn't do the trick). Everything else works, only the stored procedure blocks the import into mySQL if this first row with titles is not removed from the .csv file.

Comment: Look at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8c6713920582492c955a91b6bc7cf59 PS. There is no difference between INSERT INTO and LOAD DATA. PPS. *the stored procedure blocks the import into mySQL if this first row with titles is not removed from the .csv file.* LOAD DATA have `[IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]` clause: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html *The `IGNORE number LINES` clause can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use `IGNORE 1 LINES` to skip an initial header line containing column names.*

Comment: Yes I know that I can remove the first line with the `IGNORE` clause or manually. My expectation was to set a trigger that would take care of that and be error proof (either by skipping the import of any rows with invalid values in these fields, or by inserting POINT (0,0) for example. _If only the 1st row comes with the names of the fields, it's easy to delete it or skip n top rows, but if more rows with fields name come every 100 lines, or there are corrupted values, this geometry field blocks the import..._

Comment: Skipping is problematic. Replace with zero point - easily. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8b3f88cad65d073c1026f61fc177baa

Comment: Still the same error **Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**. Sounds illogical considering the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger's parameter !

Comment: *Still the same error* Please add into the question as an update: the code text of the trigger which you have created, the content of the CSV file which you import (3-5 rows) and LOAD DATA statement which causes the issue, desired final data state after this CSV importing.

Comment: Your [0, 90] range check on both long and lat rejects all locations except in the northern and eastern hemispheres. Most of England will be rejected, and so will Australia, the Americas, and half of Africa. For what it's worth.

Comment: To O. Jones That's a good point, although not a concern yet. I think MySql is maybe not 100% ready for geo usage... Anyway, thanks to @Akina, I'll write a script to keep this a 1 click process. I use the database as a middle man between the data collecting software, and QGIS and web statistics, so PHP may take care of the import and exports needed, it will be even easier this way. Maybe I should remove the initial post now ?